# Files on my system renamed and file types also changed automatically

Tags: windows-10, virus, filesystem-corruption

Files on my system renamed and file types also changed automatically on Windows 10. When I reasearched online I found that CTB Locker, ransomware are some of the viruses that do that. But I ran my system through Kaspersky, Malwarebytes, Eset Online scanner and they found nothing. I want to know to know what is doing this.

Running chkdsk returned nothing. Data recovery software Recuva, Easeus isnt helping either.

I want to know the root cause of this.

Anyone has any idea on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some specific information might be helpful.  At this point it sounds like you have ransomware, not all, are detectable.

Comment: If your file name extensions is hided or not?

Comment: @Ramhound : All my files are renamed and file type is changed. That includes images, pdfs, my java files, a huge truecrypt mount file that I had. The file types are random characters as well. For example, "1KATfidX.tXu" is one of the file name and "TXU" is its file type. Only some of the folders are affected and its randomly affected.

Comment: @Phoebeli : No. File extensions are not hidden. They are changed to some other type.

Comment: @Prabhat - What you describe is either malware or system corruption.  The solution is the same in either case.  Format your system and restore your personal files from a backup